# How to make bootstrap 5 validation not visible immediately before the user types (oninput)?

Tags: bootstrap-5

How to make bootstrap 5 validation not visible immediately before the user types (oninput)?

Here is the program that I use, but the program immediately provides validation to the user even though the user has not provided input interaction:

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form action=" " class="was-validated">
  <div class="userid">
    <label for="uid" class="form-label"> User Name: </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id=" uid " placeholder="Enter user_name" name=" uid " required>
    <div class="valid-feedback"> Valid data. </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please fill the user name. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="emailid">
    <label for="emid" class="form-label"> Email Id: </label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id=" emid " placeholder="Enter email_id" name=" emid " required>
    <div class="valid-feedback"> Valid data. </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please fill the email id. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="numberid">
    <label for="numid" class="form-label"> Mobile Number: </label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id=" numid " placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" name="numid" required>
    <div class="valid-feedback"> Valid data. </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please fill the mobile number. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="txt">
    <label for="txt" class="form-label"> Message: </label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="txt" placeholder="Enter message" name="txt" required></textarea>
    <div class="valid-feedback"> Valid data. </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please fill the message. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="Checked" name="remembers" required>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="Checked"> I agree on form validation.</label>
    <div class="valid-feedback"> </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"> </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info mt-2"> Submit </button>
</form>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Bootstrap validations are invoked when you hit the submit button not before that.

Comment: I mean is it possible for bootstrap validation to run dynamically, while the user is typing? before pressing the button

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have `.was-validated` on the form in the markup. You add that in your validation script.

```
<form action=" " class="needs-validation">
```

> Bootstrap scopes the `:invalid` and `:valid` styles to parent `.was-validated` class, usually applied to the `<form>`. Otherwise, any required field without a value shows up as invalid on page load.
>
> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/validation/#how-it-works

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form action=" " class="needs-validation">
  <div class="userid">
    <label for="uid" class="form-label"> User Name: </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id=" uid " placeholder="Enter user_name" name=" uid " required>
    <div class="valid-feedback"> Valid data. </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please fill the user name. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="emailid">
    <label for="emid" class="form-label"> Email Id: </label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id=" emid " placeholder="Enter email_id" name=" emid " required>
    <div class="valid-feedback"> Valid data. </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please fill the email id. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="numberid">
    <label for="numid" class="form-label"> Mobile Number: </label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id=" numid " placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" name="numid" required>
    <div class="valid-feedback"> Valid data. </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please fill the mobile number. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="txt">
    <label for="txt" class="form-label"> Message: </label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="txt" placeholder="Enter message" name="txt" required></textarea>
    <div class="valid-feedback"> Valid data. </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please fill the message. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="Checked" name="remembers" required>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="Checked"> I agree on form validation.</label>
    <div class="valid-feedback"> </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"> </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info mt-2"> Submit </button>
</form>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I mean is it possible for bootstrap validation to run dynamically, while the user is typing? before pressing the button

Comment: Sure, but not by simply adding a class to the form.